# pyodbc UPDATE throws an exception

Tags: python, azure, pyodbc

I'm making a python program that does Elo calculations for an Azure SQL database. The problem is with the last two 'cursor.execute' commands (the UPDATEs).

I took out part of the code before posting here to make it smaller, but all the variables are properly passed from the find_winner and find_loser methods-- the print commands show the right value.

When I run the program as is, it prints the change in ratings and the message from the except block. When I comment out the UPDATE methods, it doesn't print the except message. The only reason I can come up with is that the variables from the tuple from find_winner and find_loser aren't being entered into the SQL statement properly.

I tried running it with ? and '%s'  instead of winner_new_rating and winner_id, but none of the 3 versions worked.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? What's the proper way of entering parameters stored in variables?

```
def rate():
    try:
        (winner_rating,winner_name,winner_id) = find_winner()
        (loser_rating,loser_name,loser_id) = find_loser()

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        print(winner_name, "wins", winner_rating, "-->", winner_new_rating)
        print(loser_name, "loses:", loser_rating, "-->", loser_new_rating)

        cursor.execute("UPDATE KIDS SET Rating = winner_new_rating WHERE LocalID = winner_id")
        cursor.execute("UPDATE KIDS SET Rating = loser_new_rating WHERE LocalID = loser_id")

        conn.commit()

    except:
        print("Rate method error")
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Oops, not an exception message. It just prints the message from the except block.

Comment: So catch the exception and print the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE KIDS SET Rating = ? WHERE LocalID = ?", 
        str(winner_new_rating), winner_id)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE KIDS SET Rating = ? WHERE LocalID = ?",
        str(loser_new_rating), loser_id)
except DatabaseError as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: That's one of the iterations I tried.

https://gyazo.com/5314456156ede0b019f48bb6f831a166

Here's a screenshot of what happens when I run that code.

Comment: There's no error message. I don't actually know how to change the except block to display the type of error

Comment: OK I've added it to my answer.

Comment: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=StringVar', 'HY105')

Comment: So are your `winner_new_rating`, `winner_id` variables strings or numbers?

Comment: winner_new_rating is an int, winner_id is a string

Comment: Try stringifying the numbers with `str()`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It took a while because I messed up other code while trying to make that work, but that worked.